# iron-router-progress - change color of progress bar and spinner

Tags: meteor, less, iron-router

I am using iron-routers-progress package and using its default setting. I tried to change the color by adding .less file and added:

```
#iron-router-progress {
    background-color : white;
    box-shadow : 0 0 5px blue;
}

#iron-router-progress.spinner:before {
    border-color : darkorange;
}
```

But it didn't work. Can someone help me out?

Comment: pretty sure you're not using right less. Are you sure you are doing things right? Is it installed and compilling right your .less file? If you don't know, just quick-dirty hack this by adding !important at the end of your css line, would work but it's clearly not the cleaner way.

Comment: Thanks, i didn't add less package. After adding less package its working. Thanks a lot!